# Firefox: How to stay on the current tab when I open a new tab using "Search Google for " context menu?

Tags: firefox, context-menu, browser-tabs

I have a habit of opening several new tabs using "Search Google for " and "Define " (Google dictionary) context menus, but Firefox always shifts the focus to the new tab. Is there a way to switch this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help you for the "Search Google for" but not for the "Define" as I don't have this add-on installed. 
You need to enter about:config into the location bar of firefox, confirm the info notification (in case it shows up), search for the preference named browser.search.context.loadInBackground & toggle it to true by double-clicking it. That's it. Hopefully it it also work for the "Define" add-on as well

Comment: Update on Define plugin: It has an option to not switch the focus to that tab.